# Как решить проблему с повторным открытие вкладок на bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap, bootstrap4, tab

Есть блок с элементами, подробное содержимое которых по задумке должно открываться при клике на ссылку подробнее.

Для этого я реализовал на вкладках `bootstrap`, но почему-то отрабатывает такой подход только для первого раза, при повторном нажатии на выбранные ссылки соответствующий блок подробным содержимым не открывает. [все ссылки становятся активными и не уходят в начальное положение]

Как это можно решить?

```js
$('#nozzle-1').tab('show');
```

```css
.nozzles-block {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="nozzles-block container-fluid">
  <div class="nozzle">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100">
    <p>текст</p>
    <p><a data-toggle="tab" href="#nozzle-1">Подробнее</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="nozzle">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100">
    <p>текст</p>
    <p><a data-toggle="tab" href="#nozzle-2">Подробнее</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="nozzle">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100">
    <p>текст</p>
    <p><a data-toggle="tab" href="#nozzle-3">Подробнее</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="nozzle">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100">
    <p>текст</p>
    <p><a data-toggle="tab" href="#nozzle-4">Подробнее</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="nozzle">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100">
    <p>текст</p>
    <p><a data-toggle="tab" href="#nozzle-5">Подробнее</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tab-content collapse show container">
  <div class="tab-pane fade in show" id="nozzle-1">
    <div class="row">Подробное содержание 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nozzle-2">
    <div class="row">Подробное содержание 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nozzle-3">
    <div class="row">Подробное содержание 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nozzle-4">
    <div class="row">Подробное содержание 4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nozzle-5">
    <div class="row">Подробное содержание 5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('#nozzle-1').tab('show');
```

```css
.nozzles-block {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nozzles-block container-fluid nav">
  <li class="nozzle">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100">
    <p>текст</p>
    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#nozzle-1">Подробнее</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nozzle">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100">
    <p>текст</p>
    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#nozzle-2">Подробнее</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nozzle">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100">
    <p>текст</p>
    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#nozzle-3">Подробнее</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nozzle">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100">
    <p>текст</p>
    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#nozzle-4">Подробнее</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nozzle">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100">
    <p>текст</p>
    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#nozzle-5">Подробнее</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content collapse show container">
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nozzle-1">
    <div class="row">Подробное содержание 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nozzle-2">
    <div class="row">Подробное содержание 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nozzle-3">
    <div class="row">Подробное содержание 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nozzle-4">
    <div class="row">Подробное содержание 4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nozzle-5">
    <div class="row">Подробное содержание 5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если начать убирать некоторые вещи из вашего кода (обёртки `<div class="nozzle">`) и кое-что добавить из [документации по бутстрапу](https://bootstrap-4.ru/docs/4.0/components/navs/), то сразу всё начинает работать. Если покопаться в исходниках бутстрапа, то можно увидеть будет следующее:

```
const Selector = {
  DROPDOWN              : '.dropdown',
  NAV_LIST_GROUP        : '.nav, .list-group',
  ACTIVE                : '.active',
  ACTIVE_UL             : '> li > .active',
  DATA_TOGGLE           : '[data-toggle="tab"], [data-toggle="pill"], [data-toggle="list"]',
  DROPDOWN_TOGGLE       : '.dropdown-toggle',
  DROPDOWN_ACTIVE_CHILD : '> .dropdown-menu .active'
}
```

а также в методе `show` можно увидеть отсылки на списки:

```
const itemSelector = listElement.nodeName === 'UL' || listElement.nodeName === 'OL' ? Selector.ACTIVE_UL : Selector.ACTIVE
```

Это я к тому, что не спроста есть документация и примеры в ней. Потому что логика завязана на заранее прописанных селекторах (см. выше). Я рекомендовал бы вам взять один из примеров, подходящих вам и уже его кастомизировать (т.е. добавлять обёрткам класс `nozzle`, добавлять дополнительный контент и прочее)

Comment: я с вами полностью согласен, что если взять пример из исходников `bootstrap`, то все будет работать как должно.
Но, если убрать `обёртки <div class="nozzle">` и все остальное, то исчезнет полностью и имеющаяся структура блоков.
`Я рекомендовал бы вам взять один из примеров`
Это и есть задача, что таких примеров не нахожу, в этом-то и проблема состоит как сделать так, чтобы оставить и структуру и возможность переключения по табам с подгрузкой инфы.

Comment: @Вася не вижу никаких преград взять пример из документации, где вместо обёртки в виде `div` нарисован `li` и уже к нему добавить класс `nozzle` и т.д. `как сделать так, чтобы оставить и структуру` - нужно изначально опираться на документацию, а не подгонять её функционал под свою